# Integrate Google Signin to existing OAuth

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, google-signin

Back-end server in Java, stores users in DB.
Someone integrated OAuth2 in the app.
An user logs in and then in any place I can call this code:

```
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
```

to get the currently logged in user.
Now I want to use Google Signin. I have back-end code that receives a Google token and I can extract the information it has.
My question is: How do I integrate this with the current OAuth2 login process so that when I call the code above I get the Google signed in user?
I.e. how do I tell OAuth2 - now use this Google token instead of username/password to login user?
Or if someone can point me to sample code that does it?

Thank you